# How can I check whether the given function or vector field is path-dependent or path-independent?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals

I understand that the fundamental theorem on line integrals can be used only to those vector fields that are path-independent.

It would be so troublesome if I go on checking different paths and then stating it as path-independent. Is there any methods/techniques using which I can clearly differentiate a path-independent vector field?

Comment: You need your vector field to be conservative. That means literally that it is the gradient of some function, but you can at least check if it's irrotational ($\nabla\times v=0$). Not sure if irrotational implies conservative, but conservative implies irrotational, so that if it's not irrotational, it's not conservative. (Domain connected means irrotational implies conservative.)

Comment: So, its sufficient to prove the field as irrotational. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in 3-D Euclidean space, then a vector field $\vec{A}: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as the gradient of a scalar field if and only if its curl is zero:
$$
\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \vec{A} = \vec{\nabla} f \text{ for some $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.}
$$
Proving the arrow going to the left above is relatively easy (it follows from assuming that the mixed partials of $f$ are equal).  Proving the arrow going to the right is noticeably harder, but can still be done.

This can easily be extended to 2-D Euclidean space by briefly "pretending" that you have a vector field that doesn't depend on a third Euclidean coordinate, taking the curl, and seeing if it vanishes.  In higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces, the idea of the "curl" must be replaced by something called the *exterior derivative*, but a similar statement still holds.

And in non-Euclidean spaces, the failure of the above statement to be true tells you something deep and beautiful about the topology of the space;  the study of this phenomenon is called *de Rham cohomology*, which I never miss an opportunity to mention if I'm given an opening because I think it's so darn cool.

Comment: Okay, I will try to analyse the things from topology. Anyways, its comparitevely easy to check the field to be irrotational. I will follow that.